# Displaying multiple layers, ArcGIS javascript api

Tags: javascript, dojo, arcgis-js-api

I am a codeacademy, Javascript idiot, please help. All I want to do is understand why the following code won't work. It should display the oceans map with the marine protected areas on top of it but only shows the oceans map. Firebug says that new ArcGISDynamicLayer is not a constructor but the API ref says it is the appropriate constructor.

I'm trying to learn so would appreciate descriptions of how it's not working as well as solutions.
Thanks

```
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
          <title></title>
          <style>
              html,
              body,
              #mapDiv {
                  padding: 0;
                  margin: 0;
                  height: 100%;
              }
          </style>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/esri/css/esri.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/js/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/viewer.css">
          <script type="text/javascript">
              var djConfig = {
                  parseOnLoad: true
              };
          </script>
          <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.9/"></script>
          <script>
              require(["esri/map",
                      "esri/layers/ArcGISMapServiceLayer"
                  ],
                  function (Map, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer) {
                      map = new Map("mapDiv", {
                          center: [-56.049, 38.485],
                          zoom: 3,
                          basemap: "oceans"
                      });
                      var newLayer = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://egisws02.nos.noaa.gov/ArcGIS/rest/services/MPA/MPA_Inventory/MapServer", {
                          "id": "mpa"
                      });
                      map.addLayer(newLayer);
                  });
          </script>
      </head>

      <body>

          <body class="claro">
              <div id="mapDiv"></div>
          </body>
      </body>

      </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to answer my own question, in my require statement I was requesting ArcGISMapServiceLayer, and then declaring my function variable for ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer. Solved the issue and plodding forward with the next steps of toggling between them.

Any ideas on how to debug something like this for the future?

Comment: Seems like you debugged it just fine. :)  One trick I use with Dojo require statements is one required module per line in both the array and function parameters, both with the same level of indentation -- this will provide a visual check for matching the correct items.